# How to use .pdb files for debugging in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, pdb-files

I have a .dll file and its respective .pdb file. I do not have it's source code. Is it possible to debug the part of code from that dll using .pdb file.

What could be the optimal way to debug using .pdb files.

Thanks 

Vijay

Comment: The optimal way is with source code.  Without it, this gets rapidly pointless and works about as well as having no .pdb.  Red Gate sells a decompiler that recovers source code and shows it while debugging.  .NET Reflector VSPro, costs a hundred ninety bucks.  No idea how well it works.

Comment: Its extremly hard to debug a dll which you do not have the source code to.  The reflector add-on does do what it claims to do, allows you to debug an reference assembly, this of course assumes many things.  Much easier and cheaper to get the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pdb's map areas of the binary (exe or dll) to the original source code files. AFAIK They don't contain the code itself so you won't be able to see with source code unless you code files.